# Forcing Landscape On Android PhonGap Build

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to make my app **force rotate to landscape on Android**. 
I know there are methods to do this with the normal Linux program but i was wanting to know whether it is possible to do so on **PhoneGap Build**
Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good time to read the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29).

The section you want is in `Configuring` -> `Preferences` -> [`Multi-Platform`](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#_multi_platform)

DATE: 2015-11-30 - Sorry forgot to include this:

`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`